# JavaScript file included in <script> tag does not run when using CodeSandbox service

Tags: javascript, html, codesandbox

I'm using CodeSandbox.io

I wrote some JavaScript that runs fine when I include it in  tags in the file.

But when I put it in a separate file, it doesn't run

Here is my code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-voice-6kqtq3?file=/index.html

My HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- 
      html comment, not code, not displayed on page 
    -->
    <form name="hi" action="https://www.google.com/search">
      <input type="text" name="q" size="20" id="search_query" />
      <br /><br />
      <input
        type="button"
        onclick="return omg2('thank you', 'goldenrod', 20);"
        value="OMG"
      />
      <input
        type="button"
        onclick="return omg2('thanks', 'aquamarine')"
        value="omg"
      />
      <input type="submit" value="google" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
      function omg2(value, bgcolor, size = 40) {
        //var textbox = document.hi.q;
        var textbox = document.getElementById('search_query');
        textbox.value = value + '; ' + 'size = ' + size ;
        textbox.style.backgroundColor = bgcolor;
        textbox.setAttribute('size', size);
      }
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-river-mf9fxt?file=/script.js is empty

Comment: The sandbox also doesn't have `<script src="./script.js"></script>`?

Comment: My apologies, I posted the wrong sandbox link initially.

Comment: The JavaScript shown here does not match that in the CodeSandbox. It is missing the arguments in CodeSandbox.